# redirect php page success login

Tags: php, redirect

A very nice person from inhere helped me making a login form with cookies, and it works perfectly fine. So when I login I get redirected to home.php, where I also can logout. But I am not quite sure of something. If I have a succesfull login, I would like to get redirected to profile.php, and not home.php?

Best Regards
Julie

index.php:

```
    <?php
    $error='';
    if( !isset( $_SESSION ) ) session_start();

    if( !isset( $_SESSION['username'])) include('login.php'); 
    else exit( header('Location: home.php') ); 
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <title>PHP Login Form with Session</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' type='text/css' />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>PHP Login Form with Session</h1>
        <div class='loginBox'>
            <h3>Login Form</h3>
            <br><br>
            <form method='post' action=''>
                <label>Username:</label><br>
                <input type='text' name='username' placeholder='username' /><br><br>
                <label>Password:</label><br>
                <input type='password' name='password' placeholder='password' /><br><br>
                <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Login' /> 
            </form>
            <div class='error'><?php echo $error;?></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

login.php:

```
    <?php
    /* login.php */

    if( !isset( $_SESSION ) ) session_start();
    include('dbconfic.inc.php' );

    $error = '';

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {


        if( empty( $_POST['username'] ) || empty( $_POST['password'] ) ){

            $error = 'Both fields are required.';

        } else {

            /* 
                Use prepared statements - mitigates agsint sql injection.
                Use placeholders in the sql which are used by the `bind_param` statement
            */
            $sql='SELECT `uid` FROM `users` WHERE `username`=? AND md5( `password` )=? limit 1 ';
            $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
            if( !$stmt ) exit('Failed to prepare sql statement');
            /* 
                md5 is not recommended for password hashing as it is generally considered to be broken
                bind the variables to the placeholders & execute the sql
            */
            $username=$_POST['username']; 
            $password=md5( $_POST['password'] ); 

            $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password ); 
            $res=$stmt->execute();


            /* bind the result of the query to a variable */
            $stmt->bind_result( $login_user );
            while( $stmt->fetch() ){
                /* go through recordset ( 1 record ) */
                $_SESSION['username'] = $login_user;
            }

            $stmt->close();
            $db->close();

            if( isset( $_SESSION['username'] ) ) exit( header( 'location: home.php' ) );
            else $error='Incorrect username or password.';
        }
    }
?>
```

home.php:

```
<?php
    /* home.php */
    if( !isset( $_SESSION ) ) session_start();
    if( !isset( $_SESSION['username'] ) ) exit( header('Location: index.php') );

?>
 <!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Home</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1 class="hello">Hello, <em><?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?>!</em></h1>
        <br><br><br>
        <a href="logout.php" style="font-size:18px">Logout?</a>
        <a href="test.php">test</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried to change header('Loacation: index.php') to  header('Location: profile.php') after successful authentication?

Comment: thank you for the answer. Is it on the login.php?

Comment: It works now. I was trying to put the code over in another project, so it must be someplace else the error is. I will look more to it. Thank you. But do I also need to change home.php in index.php to profile.php?

Comment: You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure) and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: Your question is unclear. Where is the code for the profile.php page?

Comment: *"I would like to get redirected to profile.php, and not home.php?"* - Ok, so change all instances of `home.php` to `profile.php`, *n'est-ce pas Sam?* @JayBlanchard

Comment: *I believe so Ralph.* But who am I say @Fred-ii-?

Comment: *No idea mi amico Sam* @JayBlanchard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its make only a difference in the file structure else it would be for the client side no problem. Also do that with my index.php (Also my main page and with login the profile page).

Tip: Don't use md5 encryttion for passwords. Use the PHP 5.x password hashing libary. MD5 and SHA are today unsafe. Passwors_hashing libary is the securest way with hashing passwords

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try to study on that one. Do you know a good tutorial somewhere?

Comment: Yes find a really good tutorial http://www.sitepoint.com/hashing-passwords-php-5-5-password-hashing-api/

Comment: While an upvote would be nice, your response doesn't answer the question *"I would like to get redirected to profile.php, and not home.php?"*

Comment: Do I need to change to profile.php only on login.php or also on index.php?

Comment: No that was only an example you can named whatever you want

Comment: But if you look at my exsampel in my question. Do I need to change the home.php in index and login, or only in one of them?

Comment: If the use should login first rename the login.php to index.php if the user should redirct to the home.php first rename home.php to index.php

Comment: Please look at my question. It is not what I mean. I have 3 files here. nr.1 : index.php, 2: login.php, 3: home.php. I want to redirect a user to profile.php after the user has logged in. Should I change the statement in:
1: index.php or 
2: login.php? 

if( isset( $_SESSION['username'] ) ) exit( header( 'location: home.php' ) );
            else $error='Incorrect username or password.';

Comment: In the login.php the if Statement is at the righr place and in every file where is content that only successful logged in users can see and dont use exit (header ("...")); only header(".."); is enough